# migrate desktop custom control to web ?ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, web-user-controls

I need a web control that is available in desktop version like this link 
[Gantt chart custom control](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029252/Csharp-Winform-Gantt-Chart?msg=5318935#xx5318935xx)

This is a gantt chart its example 2 is of mine use that I am not able to find any where on internet so i decided to migrate it to website now how to do that I want to implemenet same in ASP.NET , or any body have similar example like that in middle one see link and help me

How to migrate desktop custom user control to web?

Comment: similar to that https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml

 but where is its code

Comment: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/ - control from your sample

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline this also works but any how we have to search answer desktop to web migration of custom control as in link let migrate given link control to web in question'